# Create a TimePickerDialog using the FragmentDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, time, datepicker

I want to create a TimePickerDialog using FragmentDialog and exchange data between my fragment and the TimePickerDialog . I already created a DatePickerDialog but I don't know how to create a TimePickerDialog . I want that when the user click the button in my fragment TimePickerDialog appear .
This is how I create The **DatePickerDialog** :

> import java.util.Calendar; import java.util.Date; import
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.app.AlertDialog; import
>   android.app.Dialog; import android.content.DialogInterface; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; import android.view.View;
>   import android.widget.DatePicker; import
>   android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
>
> public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
>       public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "criminalintent.DATE";
>
> ```
> Date mDate;
>
> public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
>     Bundle args = new Bundle();
>     args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
>
>     DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
>     fragment.setArguments(args);
>
>     return fragment;
> }
>
> private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
>     if (getTargetFragment() == null) 
>         return;
>
>     Intent i = new Intent();
>     i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
>
>     getTargetFragment()
>         .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
> }
>
> @Override
> public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     mDate = (Date)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);
>
>     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
>     calendar.setTime(mDate);
>     int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
>     int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
>     int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>
>     View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
>         .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
>
>     DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePicker);
>     datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {
>         public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
>             mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
>
>             // update argument to preserve selected value on rotation
>             getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
>         }
>     });
>
>     return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
>         .setView(v)
>         .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
>         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>                 sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
>             }
>         })
>         .create();
> } }
> ```

**CrimeFragment**

> import java.util.Date; import java.util.UUID;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import android.text.Editable;
>   import android.text.TextWatcher; import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>   import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import
>   android.webkit.WebView.FindListener; import android.widget.Button;
>   import android.widget.CheckBox; import android.widget.CompoundButton;
>   import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener; import
>   android.widget.EditText;
>
> public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
>       public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "criminalintent.CRIME_ID";
>
> ```
> private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
> private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
>
> Crime mCrime;
> EditText mTitleField;
> Button mDateButton;
> CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
> Button mTime;
> String time;
> public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
>     Bundle args = new Bundle();
>     args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
>
>     CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
>     fragment.setArguments(args);
>
>     return fragment;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
>     mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
> }
>
> public void updateDate() {
>     mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
> }
>   public void updateTime() {
>
> }
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);
>
>     mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
>     mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
>     mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
>             mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
>         }
>
>         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after) {
>             // this space intentionally left blank
>         }
>
>         public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
>             // this one too
>         }
>     });
>
>     mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
>     updateDate();
>     mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {                                 
>             FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
>                     .getSupportFragmentManager();
>             DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment
>                 .newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
>             dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
>             dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);                 
>         }
>     });
>     mTime = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_time);
>
>     mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
>     mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
>     mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
>             // set the crime's solved property
>             mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
>         }
>     });
>
>
>
>     return v;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
>     if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
>         Date date = (Date)data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
> ```
>
> mCrime.setDate(date);
>                updateDate();
>
> ```
>     }
> } }
> ```

Now I want to create a TimePickerDialog  .

Comment: What android version are you supporting?

Comment: minimum required SDK of  8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DialogFragmentTimePicker extends DialogFragment implements OnTimeSetListener {

public static final String ARG_HOUR = "hour";

public static final String ARG_MINUTE = "minute";

private OnTimeSetListener mListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    int hour, minute;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        hour = getArguments().getInt(ARG_HOUR);
        minute = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MINUTE);
    } else {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void setOnTimeSetListener(OnTimeSetListener listener) {

    mListener = listener;
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onTimeSet(view, hourOfDay, minute);
    }
}
```

}